# Error: DDL statements are not allowed in transactions while running setup:upgrade. Running Data Patch

Tags: magento2, patches, magento2.3.1, setup-script, declarative-schema

Magento 2.3.1

After making the data patch @ following location

vendor/ModuleName/Setup/Patch/Data/AddMyColumnPatch.php

code given below for AddMyColumnPatch.php. When I run bin/magento setup:upgrade to get this patch installed I get following error at cli.

> DDL statements are not allowed in transactions

I have used following file as reference to add column to my table using data patch.

> vendor/magento/module-quote/Setup/Patch/Data/InstallEntityTypes.php
>   Follow lines from 47 to 65

My AddMyColumnPatch.php code is:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;


use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 */
class AddressSuburbPatch implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
     * Attribute Code of the Custom Attribute
     */
    const CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'my_column';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    private $quoteSetupFactory;


    /**
     * @var Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory
     */
    private $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,    
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {

        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;          
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;            
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();


        $this->logger->debug('DDL Statements error');

        $quoteSetup = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $quoteSetup->addAttribute('quote_address', self::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE, ['type' => 'text']);

        $salesSetup = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $salesSetup->addAttribute('order_address', self::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE, ['type' => 'text']);

        $this->logger->debug('Script working');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {

        return [

        ];
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {

        return [];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through Declarative Schema docs again and referencing core magento code for Quote Module and Paypal Module I have figured that if you want to add a field into the existing table in Magento 2.3 you should use Configure declarative schema for that. Read more -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

So create a db_schema.xml file under Vendor/ModuleName/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="quote_address" resource="checkout" comment="Sales Flat Quote Address">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="suburb" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Suburb for Quote Address"/>

    </table>
    <table name="sales_order_address" resource="sales" comment="Sales Flat Order Address">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="mycolumn" nullable="true" length="255" comment="mycolumn for Sales Order Address"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Then generate whitelist for your db_schema as follows

```
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_ModuleName
```

Run again and your column will be added to quote_address and order_sales_address tables.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

However, further investigation revealed that there is no need of making data patch for adding columns in flat tables quote_address and sales_order_address. Only declaring columns in db_schema.xml will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

It should also be noted that you can't make schema updates because you're implementing `DataPatchInterface`. Check out patch files which implement `SchemaPatchInterface`. Its a simple change to your existing code and then it should work.